# Google Maps components look incorrect

Tags: google-maps, cordova

I have loaded Google Maps Engine in my mobile PhoneGap application for display maps.

But Components, such as:left slider, baloon, balloon shadow looks incorrect. You can see it at
web-page [web page with maps](http://phonegap.qulix.com/locator.html?engine=google)

What have I made incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a css problem. remove (or override) the rule min-width and max-width (among others) that apply to the map; they are in style.css

If you use the developer tools in Chrome, you can see (and dynamically edit) the css rules that apply to each element.